# How to return a dtype(object) in flask

Tags: python, numpy, flask

I'm trying to build a FLASK application. In one route, i want the browser to print the output of a function which uses numpy. But when the code is run, it gives error as follows.

I have this function with no decorators.

```
def get_similar_places(userID):
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import pymysql
    import pandas as pd
    db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://root:VC@travel.c5dq5zer.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/traveem'
    db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
    df = pd.read_sql("select * from MatrixData where UserID = "+str(userID), con=db_connection)
    places = list(df.columns[1:])
    vector = df.iloc[0][1:]
    visited_places = [places[i] for i in range(len(places)) if vector[i] == 1]
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Similarity', con=db_connection)
    df.index = df.columns
    score = df.dot(vector).div(df.sum(axis=1))
    score = score.nlargest(10+len(visited_places))
    score = score.drop(visited_places)
    return [score.index, visited_places]
```

Then, I am calling this function like this:

```
@app.route('/cfoutput')
def collaborative_filtering():
    # reco = get_similar_places(userID = 1)
    # print(reco)
    #print(reco[1])
    return get_similar_places(userID = 1)
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
Index(['kunti betta (near srirangapatna)', 'kudremukh (near sringeri)',
       'kukke sumbrahmanya temple (near mangalore)',
       'unchalli falls (near jog falls)', 'madhugiri (near bangalore)',
       'horanadu annapoorneshwari temple (near sringeri)',
       'jamalabad fort (near mangalore)', 'hemavathi dam (near sakleshpur)',
       'agni gudda hill / agani peak (near sakleshpur)', 'srirangapatna'],
      dtype='object')
['bangalore', 'harangi dam (near coorg)', 'dandeli']
```

But,in the browser,  I'm getting the error as

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.
```

I tried to use Respone, make_response, sending as json. No options worked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to `return return {score.index, visited_places}` instead of []. This should fix the issue. Or use `json.dumps`

Comment: return {score.index, visited_places} dint work. TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a Index.